# Why is an assembly .exe file?

Tags: .net, clr

Assembly in .net Framework is, as I understand, intermediate language file + some metadata, manifest and maybe something else.

CLR translates an assembly to the machine code, which can be executed on the given local machine.

That means that assembly shouldn't be executable by the machine before being processed by CLR. If it's so, then why does it have .exe extension, which is executable on Windows machines?

Comment: For a detailed summary of why this works see this [article](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/coding-dotnet/net-portable-executable-file-11836).

Comment: Edited tags; [assembly] is for assembly-language questions.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since Windows needs to create a process and the first thing .exe will do is to **host CLR** by loading **mscoree**.

From [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621632):

> After Windows has examined the EXE
>   file's header to determine whether to
>   create a 32-bit process, a 64-bit
>   process, or a WoW64 process, Windows
>   loads the x86, x64, or IA64 version of
>   MSCorEE.dll into the process's address
>   space. On an x86 version of Windows,
>   the x86 version of MSCorEE.dll can be
>   found in the C:\Windows\System32
>   directory. On an x64 or IA64 version
>   of Windows, the x86 version of
>   MSCorEE.dll can be found in the
>   C:\Windows\ SysWow64 directory,
>   whereas the 64-bit version (x64 or
>   IA64) can be found in the
>   C:\Windows\System32 directory (for
>   backward compatibility reasons). Then,
>   the process' primary thread calls a
>   method defined inside MSCorEE.dll.
>   This method initializes the CLR, loads
>   the EXE assembly, and then calls its
>   entry point method (Main). At this
>   point, the managed application is up
>   and running.

Answer (score 7):

I have recently written a [blog post](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/simonc/archive/2011/03/28/100993.aspx) on the CLR stub in a .NET assembly and how it fits inside the PE file executable format. The whole series can be found [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/simonc/archive/category/1070.aspx).

Essentially, inside a .NET assembly is a tiny bit of native code that starts the CLR. However, this code only exists for backwards-compatibility. From Windows XP, the OS loader natively knows to load the CLR for executable that have the CLI header in them.

Answer (score 3):

A .NET .exe is a special kind of .exe that will first load up the CLR (Common Language Runtime). It will then compile the IL code inside the .exe through the CLR.

An .exe compiled through the .NET framework is a kind of [Portable Executable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable). The .exe has a CLR Header and CLR Data section. When the .exe loads, the OS will yield control to the CLR. The CLR Data section in the .exe has a metadata and an IL (Intermediate Language) segment. The metadata segment contains information about the assembly (such as the assembly manifest). The IL segment contains the code for the program in IL format. This is an intermediate format similar to Java bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's still an EXEcutable.

Comment: Well, yes. But they are not compiled into IL-code that is invented by Microsoft ;)

Comment: Heh, so your answer becomes "because MS said so" :P

Comment: Yep, but that doesn't sound as witty as `Since it's still an EXEcutable.` :P

Comment: I admit you've got me there :P