# what is the difference between an ordinary exe file and the exe file generated from .net windows applications

Tags: .net

what is the difference between an ordinary exe file and the exe file generated from .net windows applications.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

EXE generated by .NET has a *normal PE header* but then has **instructions to load MSCorEE.DLL**. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475646/why-is-an-assembly-exe-file/5475681#5475681).

Basically according to [CLR via C#](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780735627048) .NET EXE's **Managed Module** contains (in this **order**):

- PE32 or PE32+ header
- CLR header
- Metadata
- IL Code

Comment: @Hans you are absolutely right. This is `Parts of a Managed Module`. Just corrected.

Comment: @Aliostad. Will i get a good understanding of the .net framework from the `CLR via C#` book, as i can read it. I thought that u can help me choose the right book for better fundamental concepts of the .net framework.

Comment: This book is an advanced one. It is a must-read book but after you learn the basic - if you already know the basics then it is excellent.

Comment: i know a bit.. but i will read it to gain more indepth knowledge. Thanks for your reply. Your reply is highly appreciated.

Comment: In that case it is an excellent book. I have read each edition multiple times, perhaps 10 times all in all!

Comment: Wondering if any of you could help me out over at server fault with a somewhat related question, but more of a permissions issue.  See my comments in the question as well.  http://serverfault.com/questions/429263/net-console-application-exe-cant-access-mapped-drive-that-points-to-unc-path

Answer (score 0):

None, they are both executable files.

EDIT:

OK, I can see that wasn't very helpful. In one respect they are the same since they both trigger the same action from the operating system to start with, but as has been explained, there is deeper magic going on and that's more likely to be what the OP wanted to know.