# mscorlib.dll in .net CLR

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mscorlib.dll & System.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402582/mscorlib-dll-system-dll)

What does mscorlib.dll do in CLR when we have system.dll..?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mscorlib.dll & System.dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402582/mscorlib-dll-system-dll) and yet [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566534/is-mscorlib-dll-a-clr)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[mscorlib.dll](http://dll.paretologic.com/detail.php/mscorlib)