# C dll return multiple variables to C#

Tags: c#, c, dll, return-type

I have a dll written in C that gets imported into a C# application. All I need from the dll is read out a few values from a hardware device, the actual read process is done by a function in the C dll.
Now I want to read out all the values with this single function and return them to C# in an fast and easy way.
It is a very "general" multi plattform C library that consists of a few functions to handle the communication with said hardware device. I'm looking for a general "C to C#" answer that doesn't have to be specific for my case.

I'm not very experienced in C and C# which makes the task rather complicated (I have no choice about the language).
What would be a smart way to do this in C and how do I declare it in C and how I do import it properly in C#?

Here some Pseudo code to make my question a bit clearer. Thats not valid code but should make clear what I'm after
C:

```
int [] read(){

int results [3];

results[0] = getPosition();
results[1] = getOrientation();
results[2] = getTouch();

return results;
}
```

C#

```
[DllImport("myDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int[] read();

int [] cReturn = new int[3];
cReturn = read();
```

I tried returning an int array and marshal it in C#, as all my values are int types but it seems returning arrays isn't something you would do in C.

I found quite a few examples for C++ but none of them worked with C as they used C++ specific functions.

Comment: Your question is too general.  I think you're going to need to post some code.  The signature of the method in your C DLL would be a good start.

Comment: Declare a struct and pass it by reference.  Like int Foo(struct info* retval)

Comment: Currently no access to my code. I will try to add it in later.
Though I would like a general answer as I faced this issue a lot and always came back to using a single function for every variable which is kind of silly.

Comment: A "C dll" can host different kinds of code, and it's important to know what type you've got before you try to call into it from C#.  The DLL could be a COM (component object model) DLL, or it could be a simple library of compiled functions.

See this article to help you identify what you're working with - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420726/how-can-i-detect-the-type-of-a-dll-com-net-win32

Comment: It is the former. I will add that info.

Comment: *The latter, sorry. Really just a bunch of pure C functions to call without the need of any plattform specific APIs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have your C API set the values into pointers passed as arguments, ie:

```
void your_c_function(int* value1, int* value2)
{
    *value1 = 42;
    *value2 = 43;
}
```

You can then PInvoke this by `ref`:

```
[DllImport("your_dll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int your_c_function(ref int value1, ref int value2);
```

Note that you can also define a `struct` in C, and pass the entire struct by pointer, if there are many values to set.  This will require recreating the struct definition on the managed side, however.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that this is possible. How do I access the values of the pointers after calling the function though if the C function is a void? I'm not exactly familiar with this concept.

Comment: Nevermind, the MSDN article about "ref" explains it very well.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx
Thanks for your simple answer.